# Playing two sounds simultaneously - Android

Tags: android, audio, merge, android-mediaplayer, mixing

Is it possible to play two sound (mp3) files at the same time? I have tried using two different MediaPlayer objects-

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2;
```

to play the sounds, but that does not work. I cannot use SoundPool either as the sound files in use are around 10MB each (since SoundPool doesn't work well with sound files > 3MB).

Here is some code to get familiar with my situation-

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(mediaPlayer == null)
    {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.song1);
    }
    if(mediaPlayer2 == null)
    {
    mediaPlayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.raw.song2);
    }
}
private void startPlaying() {
mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
mediaPlayer.start();
mediaPlayer2.start();
}
```

Any suggestions? Is there some way to make this 2 MediaPlayer objects approach work? If not then what other options are there? Code would be helpful!

Comment: do you want to join it together or to play the two files at the same time.

Comment: @james i need to play the two files at the same time.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am trying to get this working.

Comment: @Totem I did. Sort of. It combines the two audio files into a single file, and plays that using a single media player instance. Only issue is I haven't had the time to perfect it. There is still some noise that is generated due to the combination of the two files. Do you still need me to post some code?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say no, if you have some handy! I have been reading up on this, and I'm aware of the idea of 'summing' two files. However, I'm not sure how that would be done exactly. Perhaps it just a matter of using a '+' sign somewhere?

Comment: @Totem It's a + and ÷. Averages. I'll post the code as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So playing two audio files simultaneously is definitely an issue so I thought, another way to look at the problem would be to **combine two audio files programmatically** into one, and play that. That turned out to be simple to implement with WAV files (MP3 and other compressed formats would need to be uncompressed first?). Anyway, here's how I did it:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.emokylotheme); // Name of file 1

byte [] bytesTemp2 = fullyReadFileToBytes(new File(
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+
"/Kylo Ren/"+filename+"_morphed.wav")); // Name of file 2

byte [] sample2 = convertInputStreamToByteArray(is);
byte[] temp2 = bytesTemp2.clone();

RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile2 = new RandomAccessFile(new File(
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+
"/Kylo Ren/"+filename+"_morphed.wav"), "rw");

//seek to skip 44 bytes for WAV formats
randomAccessFile2.seek(44);
for (int n = 0; n < bytesTemp2.length; n++)
{
    bytesTemp2[n] = (byte) ((temp2[n] + (sample2[n])));
} 

randomAccessFile2.write(bytesTemp2);
randomAccessFile2.close();
```

And here are the support functions:

```
public byte[] convertInputStreamToByteArray(InputStream inputStream)
     {
     byte[] bytes= null;

     try
     {
     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

     byte data[] = new byte[1024];
     int count;

     while ((count = inputStream.read(data)) != -1)
     {
     bos.write(data, 0, count);
     }

    bos.flush();
     bos.close();
     inputStream.close();

    bytes = bos.toByteArray();
     }
     catch (IOException e)
     {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return bytes;
     }


byte[] fullyReadFileToBytes(File f) throws IOException {
        int size = (int) f.length();
        byte bytes[] = new byte[size];
        byte tmpBuff[] = new byte[size];
        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(f);
        try { 

            int read = fis.read(bytes, 0, size);
            if (read < size) {
                int remain = size - read;
                while (remain > 0) {
                    read = fis.read(tmpBuff, 0, remain);
                    System.arraycopy(tmpBuff, 0, bytes, size - remain, read);
                    remain -= read;
                } 
            } 
        }  catch (IOException e){
            throw e;
        } finally { 
            fis.close();
        } 

        return bytes;
    }
```

In essence, what the code does is: It gets the bytes of the two audio files (one is within the app in R.raw and the other is in the external storage directory), sums them up, and writes the new bytes to another file.

The issue with this code is that it generates some amount of background noise. It isn't a lot but I believe the summing up of the bytes at certain points (maybe extremas?) leads to the noise. If someone knows how to fix this, could you edit the answer and let me know.

P.S. this was for an open source voice changer app with dramatic background noise effects called Kylo Ren Voice Changer (https://github.com/advaitsaravade/Kylo-Ren-Voice-Changer)

Comment: @Totem turns out there wasn't any averaging required. Just summing up stuff.

Comment: Why does adding two files into one results in simultaneous play of them both ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used two instances of `MediaPlayer` in a `Service`. My code is similar to yours. I had some problems but finally solved it. Please check my answer here [Unable to play two MediaPlayer at same time in Nexus 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425433/unable-to-play-two-mediaplayer-at-same-time-in-nexus-5)

If you still have problems, please put your full code and the logcat error.

Answer (score -3):

You can also try to create two fragments and each play a sound.
I have another problem if i played an mp3 file, then click the back button and then start the activity again and  ican play the same file again. You can will read [Android Mediaplayer multiple instances when activity resumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498587/android-mediaplayer-multiple-instances-when-activity-resumes) play sound in the same time